# Type 'MyType' is not defined in LightSwitch Desktopclient

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I added a computed field in a LightSwitch application to be able to show a string representation of an integer field from an importerd database that has as type a self defined enum.
The code is thus:

```
     Private Sub StatusDescription_Compute(ByRef result As String)
        Dim enumValue As CompetitionStatus = Me.Status
        result = enumValue.ToString
    End Sub
```

The   `CompetitionStatus` is an enum. Visual studio's IDE accepts this syntax happily after I have added a reference to the dll that contains the enum and added an `Imports` (`using`) statement.

I find the added reference back in the LightSwitch's Server subproject (and cannot add it anywhere else.)
However, the code refuses to compile, telling me that the `CompetitionStatus`type is not defined.

What is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assembly that CompetitionStatus is defined in must be a Portable Class Library, otherwise it can't be used by the Client project (since it's a Silverlight project).  Here's some info: [How to Make Portable Class Libraries Work for You](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsplaisted/archive/2012/08/27/how-to-make-portable-class-libraries-work-for-you.aspx)